# Elasticsearch BulkIndexError after scraping website for a long time

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using scrapy to crawl certain website and store it in Elasticsearch index. I'm using bulk method to write it on Elastic like this:

```
items = []

index_action = {
    '_index': index_name,
    '_source': dict(item)
}

items.append(index_action)

if len(items) >= 10:
    helpers.bulk(es, items)
    items = []
```

So I'm sending in Bulk with ten items. However **after 3 hours of scraping** I'm starting to get this error:

```
File "/home/parser/envs/parser/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 274, in _process_bulk_chunk_success
raise BulkIndexError(f"{len(errors)} document(s) failed to index.", errors)
elasticsearch.helpers.BulkIndexError: 1 document(s) failed to index.
```

The problem is that, elasticsearch's python bulk method does not show proper error message. It just says that it can't use bulk. I can't find any logs from elasticsearch

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

`bulk` does not use `_process_bulk_chunk_success` and it *returns* errors (if running with `stats_only` which looks to be `True` by default).

So use:

```
success, errors = helpers.bulk(es, items)
print(success, errors)
```